# How do I fade one image out, another in, all on click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I think my issue would be easier to understand in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/KjR8D/4/

I am trying to fade out the Google logo on click and then automatically fade in the Yahoo logo (without clicking again).

Any help or points in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you want one of them hidden onload? Also, an `id` must be unique, if you want to use the same `id` for multiple elements, switch to a `class`.

Comment: Yes, so the Yahoo logo is hidden, then appears after the Google logo fades out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an number of issues.  Here's the fixed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KjR8D/7/

- You cannot have two elements with the same `id`; use `class` instead
- Now, we're using the `complete` callback to fade in the second image
- We're hiding the `fadein` image initially
- We're stopping the default link behavior (always a good idea; otherwise a scrolled page will jump)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for fixing my mistakes, too! If I wanted to repeat this one more time (fade Yahoo out and another image in), do I need to create a loop?

Comment: @Pat: Happy to help :)  No loop; just as a `complete` callback was added to the `fadeOut`, add a callback on the `fadeIn`.

Comment: Not be a nuisance, but can you explain that in layman's terms? I assume you mean to add `, function(){` at the end of line 10. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: `...fadeIn(duration);` becomes `...fadeIn(duration, function(){ /*this is the callback*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("a#fadeout").click(function(){
    $("#image").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $("#fadein").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

you want to hook the fadein() call on the callback of the fadeout() call.

http://jsfiddle.net/KjR8D/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<a href="#" id="fadeout"><div id="image"><img id="google" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></div></a>

<a href="#" id="fadein"><div id="image"><img id="yahoo" src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_us_061509.png"></div></a>

</body>

$(function(){
$("#yahoo").hide();
$("a#fadeout").click(function(){
    $("#google").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#yahoo").fadeIn(1000);

    });
    $("a#fadein").click(function(){
        $("#yahoo").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#google").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});

#image{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-168px;
margin-left:-168px;
}
```

sottenad's solution is neater though.